# How to display the row with the max value?

Tags: java

I am trying to display the current row that has the max value. So far I have the max value by adding the elements in the array but I am trying to display the specific row it is in. For example:

```
{4,4,4}
{5,5,5}
```

`:25 is the biggest val possible going by row to row`

The max value here would be 15 as my code looks and finds the maximum addition in each row in a 2D array. How would I get my code to display the row `{5,5,5}` as well as the actual maximum addition that is possible with the given rows.

Here is my current code:

```
public class review{
    int largestRowsSum(int[][] arr){ 
    int sum = 0;
    int largest = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        if(sum > largest){
            largest  = sum;
        }
      sum = 0;       
    }
    return largest;  
}
}
```

Comment: have a new variable being an `int []` which holds the value of `arr[i]` which is the largest

Comment: Write a second method to iterate the array and return the index (what if two rows have the same, maximum, sum) with a given sum?

Answer (score 0):

First, your current method could be simplified and `static`. Like,

```
static int largestRowsSum(int[][] arr) {
    int sum = Arrays.stream(arr[0]).sum();
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum = Math.max(Arrays.stream(arr[i]).sum(), sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Second, you could invoke that method and then iterate the array to find the *index* of the array with the matching sum. Like,

```
static int largestRowIndex(int[][] arr) {
    int target = largestRowsSum(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Arrays.stream(arr[i]).sum() == target) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Finally, call that method and use the returned index to display the row and correct sum. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 4, 4, 4 }, { 5, 5, 5 } };
    int n = largestRowIndex(arr);
    System.out.printf("The largest row is %s and the sum is %d.%n", 
            Arrays.toString(arr[n]), Arrays.stream(arr[n]).sum());
}
```

Outputs, the row {5,5,5} as well as the actual maximum,  as requested

```
The largest row is [5, 5, 5] and the sum is 15.
```